# JS colourizing part of a string

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to colourize part of a string without splitting it into char array and injecting it in `<div>`s with different colour property?

Comment: (1) Show your code and point out what the problem is. (2) 'Strings' do not have a color. Presumably you are talking about HTML. (3) `<div>` is actually the wrong element type. You should use `<span>` instead.

Comment: @Jongware I know that string doesn't have such property, thats why I said about html element div's property colour. And it doesnt matter for the question whether I use div or span.

Comment: Help us to help you. [We really do our best](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306093/2564301).

Comment: @Jongware If you think it applies to me, then I am sorry to disappoint you. I already got the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean something like.

```
<div id="r">Hello World</div>
```

and you need to add different color to each character.
try as follows:

```
var x = function(){
    return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); 
}
var elem = document.getElementById('r');
var text = elem.innerText;
var array = [];
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    array.push('<font style="color:'+x()+';">'+text[i]+'</font>');
}
var temp = '';
for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
    temp+=array[j];
}
elem.innerHTML = temp;
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the answer I wanted. Thx